# Is it possible to replace an <a> tag to it's href link within a string without using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript string that looks like this

```js
const link = `
  Checkout My Cheat Sheet:

  <a target="_blank" href="https://tailwindcomponents.com/cheatsheet/"/>

  It's awesome
`;
```

I want to convert the above text to this

```js
const link = `
  Checkout My Cheat Sheet:

  https://tailwindcomponents.com/cheatsheet/

  It's awesome
`;
```

Although I can use innerHTML, my text might contain other script tags, which might cause XSS.

Replacing `<a>` tag is enough for me right now.

Is there any possible string solution?

Comment: innerHTML doesn't run script tags...

Comment: @dandavis you can <img src="badLink" onerror="alert(1)" />

Comment: outside of template sure, but that wasn't mentioned by OP; "script tags"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOMParser can safely parse HTML strings without any possibility of unsafe code execution:

```js
const link = `
  Checkout My Cheat Sheet:

  <a target="_blank" href="https://tailwindcomponents.com/cheatsheet/"></a>

  It's awesome
`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(link, 'text/html');
for (const a of doc.querySelectorAll('a')) {
  a.replaceWith(a.href);
}
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Note that you do need a closing tag for the `<a>`.